# Synchronization on ArrayList

Tags: java, android, multithreading, arraylist

I have a loop like:

```
synchronized(list) {
    int objectsN = list.size();
    for (int i=0; i < objectsN; i++) {
        // Do stuff...
    }
}
```

`list` is a final field of an object in which this code is.

And then I have a method in the same object which calls `list.remove(index)` and it is called by the other thread while some thread is executing above code listing in an infinite loop (with sleep between single cycles) and SOMETIMES it crashes giving IndexOutOfBoundsException.

How to synchronize this list properly?

Comment: You should take a look at: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html

Comment: Can you show the code for the `other thread`. Also, multi-threaded or not, remove will always throw that exception if you pass a non-existent index.

Comment: @huidube Why is this class better than ArrayList?

Comment: Well, vector is build-in synchronized. But you better take a look on Reimeus answer. Its even a better choice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Synchronizing the remove statement would solve the concurrency.

```
synchronized (list) {
    list.remove(index);
}
```

If you use Java 8 you could use a `Collections.synchronizedList(list)` when you define your list and call `list.foreach(currentElement -> {// Do stuff...})`

```
private List<?> list;

public Constructor(list) {
    this.list = Collections.synchronizedList(list);
}

public void loopingMethod() {
    list.foreach(currentElement -> {// Do stuff...});
}

public void deletingMethod(int index) {
    list.remove(index); // This assumes the index is within bound
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Using synchronizedList and leaving synchronized block solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to take a lock on a common object if two methods intend to change the same data.  One doesn't even have to synchronize on the list object here, any object would do, but both the looping and deleting methods should use it.